# Валидация входящих данных Yii по integer

Tags: php, yii2, yii, валидация

Вечер добрый, не получается сделать валидацию входящих данных в Yii2, в модели пишу правило, но вылетает исключение.

```
['idUpdateMessage', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам, для проверки входящих данных по integer нужно писать так:

```
['idUpdateMessage', 'integer', 'integerOnly'=>true, 'message'=>'Что писать если значение не integer']
```

Comment: Можно даже без  'integerOnly'=>true, 'message'=>'Что писать если значение не integer'

Comment: Согласен, можно, но надо дать понять пользователю что мы только целочисленные значения принимаем

Comment: В yii есть стандартное сообщение

Answer (score -1):

исходя из полей вашей модели привожу пример, вам следует подставить свои поля.

```
 public function rules()
 {
      return [

    // атрибут required указывает, что name, number, subject, body обязательны для заполнения
    [['name', 'number', 'subject', 'body'], 'required'],

    // атрибут number, что в переменной number должна быть именно переменная с типом integer
    ['number', 'integer'],
];
```

}

Ссылка на русскую документацию по валидированию можно найти здесь и удачи Вам
https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/input-validation/

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/149910)